# How to Pick a type from a nested array type?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to Pick a type from another type which is a nested array.

Example
Extract the Fighter (singular) type from the Card type:

```
type Card = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    fights: (Fight & {
        fighters: Fighter[];
    })[];
}
```

If I do the following I get the `Fights` (Fight array type)

```
type Fights = Pick<Card, 'fights'>
```

How can I Pick the `Fighter` type?

Comment: You're using Pick and Extract with capital letters, which sound a lot like the `Pick` and `Extract` utility types which do two different things.   What type, specifically, should `Fights` evaluate to.  If it's just supposed to be `Fighter` then you can write `Card["fights"][number]["fighters"][number]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wen1eN).  If you want something else, please describe it precisely.

Comment: I think you can't pick Fighter out of Card because Fighter does not exist as the standalone type of any member of Card. It only exists as part of the type union with Fight. Trying to extract part of a subcomponent of a type union seems overly difficult. But I suppose it's an interesting academic exercise?

Comment: My suggestion here is for grabury to [edit] the question to clarify exactly what is being sought, preferably by removing words like Pick and Extract unless the meanings of those words happen to coincide with what Pick and Extract mean in TypeScript.  `Card["fights"][number]["fighters"][number]` is going to be equivalent to `Fighter` (unless `Fight` is defined in a weird way. Hey, can you provide a [mre] without undefined types?), but none of that uses `Pick` or an `Extract`. It's *indexing* into object types and *looking up*  the property types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type FighterType = Card['fights'][0]['fighters'][0];
```